# Differences between rails 2.3.10 and 3.0.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitorious

I recently jumped on the rails bandwagon at the end of last year so i went straight to rails version 3.0.3..

I don't have any experience with 2.* releases but i'd like to start hacking on the gitorious project (http://gitorious.org/gitorious/mainline which is the tool our company hosts it's repos on.. we run a local copy) and it runs on rails 2.3.10

What should i look out for?

Comment: I'm not to clear on your question. You want to start working on a Rails 2.x project hosted on Gitorious? Also, there are major differences in the 2.x versions - specifically which minor version (2.3.x, 2.2.x)?

Comment: Hey @Ramon sorry i should've been clearer and have ammended the question.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best is you look into the [whats new guide for rails 3.0](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html), there are old features mentioned, or what have changed.

You may want also check out the casts from Ryan Bates which covers those topics: [rails 2.3](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rails%202.3) and [rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=rails%203)